# Keypad is coming without UITextField

Tags: ipad

In an iPad application I have opened the keypad in a page .In this condition I have pressed the back button to come to previous page and then in the previous page, I don't understand why the keypad is coming though there is no text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try dismissing the keyboard anyway once you are ready to go out from the viewcontroller.

Write

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

In `ViewWillDisappear` of the viewcontroller in which you have textfield.